# Older equivalent to “concrete thought” metaphor?

Tags: expressions, idioms, metaphors, thought

What came first, *concrete* as a way to express a solid thought, or *concrete* as a solid building material?

And what I am really getting at is, prior to the invention of concrete as a building material, was there a different metaphor used to express the idea of a *concrete* thought?

Comment: Do keep in mind that concrete goes back to the Egyptians and was commonly used by the Romans.

Comment: @HotLicks True, but nobody called the stuff *concrete* until mid 19th century. Best so far - "concrete idea" - 1838, concrete as cemented sand and gravel - 1834. The use of concrete meaning not abstract goes back to 1500s.

Comment: @PhilSweet -- So it really should be called "opus caementicium thought"!

Comment: Hint:  Consult a thesaurus for antonyms of "abstract".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in a [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concrete?src=search-dict-box#synonyms) where there is a comprehensive discussion of the word and you can see that it has a long history meaning "solid", "not abstract" and so on. From its Latin origin meaning "grow together" its main meaning is "solid, stuck together".

It is the logical opposite of [discrete](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discrete#synonyms) (in separate parts) although it is not used as an antonym.

Answer (score 1):

"**Rock solid**" should do the trick.

> He used "**rock solid**" reasoning.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rock+solid

> Of course you could use "**solid as a rock**" in the same context. I'm
>   not sure which came first.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/solid+as+a+rock

Comment: But "rock solid reasoning" isn't necessarily complimentary.  I might think of it is being "dumb as a rock" :-)

Comment: But "concrete thought" isn't necessarily complimentary either. It's a statement of fact. They had only bones and stones to work with in those days. "dumb as a rock" is not the same idiom.